# How to save the photo captured with Camera in Picture Library

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I used below code to capture photo but not sure how to save it in Picture Library or Folder in Picture Library. Would appreciate your help on this.

```csharp
CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
StorageFile photo = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);


if (photo != null)
{
  BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
  IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
  bmp.SetSource(stream);
  ImageSource.Source = bmp;
  ImageSource.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

  StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

??? not sure :
     var imagefile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("MyPhoto.jpeg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

   photo.CopyAsync(storageFolder,imagefile);

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You must have to set camera and picture library access capability in manifest.

```
CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
StorageFile photo = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

//By default the photo will be stored at location
//%localappdata%\Packages\APP_PACKAGE_ID\TempState

if (photo != null)
{
    //await photo.MoveAsync(KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary);
    //OR
    await photo.MoveAsync(KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary, "DesiredPhotoName" + photo.FileType, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
}
```

Comment: It is working. Is this photo.FileType defined by the Camera as photo is storageFile that I did not define its type.  This works too:  await photo.MoveAsync(KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary, "MyPhoto" + ".jpeg", NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);   Is DesiredPhotoName means "Name" + ".jpeg"  Thanks

Comment: It's better to use `photo.FileType`, because some camera may offer different format. So we should not _hardcode_ the format.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I know what the photo fileType being defined for the Camera? Where to set the photo filetype? I think it is predefined such as jpg. Thans

Comment: That depends upon camera model. If it offers only JPEG then there will be no selection.